# Динамическое импортирование модулей в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно ли динамически импортировать модули? Например, в какой-нибудь функции. Чтобы проверить через if и импортировать в случае надобности.

Comment: Ну так вы попробуйте...

Comment: Можно. А ещё есть модуль importlib, который позволяет с импортом делать много чего удивительного и полезного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это, конечно, возможно, но очень странно и более или менее бесполезно.

Пример

```
def f(a):
    if a >= 0:
        import math
        return math.sqrt(a)
    else:
        return a

f(25)             # OK
f(-9)             # OK
math.sqrt(25)     # NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Последняя команда показывает, почему лучший импорт на уровне модуля:

```
import math

def f(a):
    if a >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(a)
    else:
        return a

f(25)             # OK
f(-9)             # OK
math.sqrt(25)     # OK
```